# I am using MYSQL for calculating the TOP-N in each subject in a student table.

Tags: mysql, groupwise-maximum

I have a student table which has student_id, score and subject

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS students 
(student_id INT(3),   subject ,VARCHAR(45),   score INT(3) );
```

The data inserted is

```
insert into students values(1,'math',70);
insert into students values(1,'science',71);
insert into students values(1,'history',72);
insert into students values(1,'english',73);
insert into students values(1,'kannada',74);
insert into students values(3,'math',50);
insert into students values(3,'science',51);
insert into students values(3,'history',52);
insert into students values(3,'english',53);
insert into students values(3,'kannada',54);
insert into students values(2,'math',60);
insert into students values(2,'science',61);
insert into students values(2,'history',62);
insert into students values(2,'english',63);
insert into students values(2,'kannada',64);
```

I am getting the required output after using the query,

```
select student_id,score,subject
    from
        (select @prev := '', @n:=0) init
    join
        (select @n := if(subject != @prev , 1, @n+1) as n,
                 @prev := subject,
                 student_id,score,subject from students
                 order by
                 subject asc, 
                 score desc
        ) x
        where n<=2
        order by subject, score desc;
```

I simply don't understand how this works, why there is a need for the join? Is this a sub-query? Will the statements in the from clause run on every row of data? Some one please explain it to me. I am learning SQL.

Note : I found this query similar to this online and I merely adapted that to suite my requirement ,this is not my work.

Comment: It has to do with the way session variables work in MySQL.

Comment: Okay. Understood. Thanks for your reply Tim.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The join is just needed so that you can initialize the variables `@prev` and `@n` in the query. This needs to be done separately from the query that you're trying to filter. You could do it before the query instead, but this keeps everything together in one self-contained query.

```
SET @prev = '';
SET @n = 0;
SELECT student_id, score, subject
FROM 
    (select @n := if(subject != @prev , 1, @n+1) as n,
             @prev := subject,
             student_id,score,subject from students
             order by
             subject asc, 
             score desc
    ) x
where n<=2
order by subject, score desc;
```

In this case the subquery is used so that you can select the `n <= 2` rows that you want.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So will the statements in the from clause run for each and every row of data? when I run the statements in the from clause separately, the output is,1 english 4 153 english
2 english 1 73 english
3 english 2 63 english
1 history 4 152 history
2 history 1 72 history
3 history 2 62 history.
How are the values for @n getting reset to 0 and starting the counter again for each subject?

Comment: The statements in the `SELECT` clause run for each row in the table. The `IF()` expression resets `@n` to `1` whenever the subject changes.

Comment: So as per what I understood, The SELECT in the from clause runs and creates a table , after completion the outer SELECT selects the specified fields. So basically the inner most query runs first.

Comment: Thanks for your time and patience Barmar